# Anchor In Foundation Doesn't Seem Right

Tags: foundation, construction

I am getting a house built, and it looks like one of my anchor bolt wasn't placed correctly (not inside the wood). I compared with a they dont all appear to be like mine. Should I be worried about this? I attached a picture of the bolt in question.

[image]

Comment: Here is the picture. Can someone help me upload to the website to make it easier ?http://s1343.photobucket.com/user/gammaupsilonpledgeclass2012/media/Screenshot_20180211-163631_zpsieu0n5eh.png.html

Comment: Other than being off set it looks fine it is possible the rebar was shifted and they hooked the rebar from the outside in.I have had a few anchors shift in the past and never failed inspection.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things in the photo: 1) anchor bolt, and 2) holddown. You must live in a “high wind” area or a “seismically active” area.

1) The anchor bolt is used to secure the plate to the foundation. The plywood sheathing is then nailed into the plate to create a “shear panel” (shear wall). It’s a bit unusual to me because it has a head. Usually the bolt’s threaded end extends out of the concrete a few inches. Then when the plate is installed a nut and washer is installed AND TIGHTENED DOWN. This installation does not allow it to be tightened. (Maybe they drive the anchor bolt deep enough that the plate sits tight to the concrete.). The 3” square washer is to keep the plate from pulling off the foundation wall. (I’d check to make sure the anchor bolts have a hook (about 1” hook) so it doesn’t pull out. It should also be about 10” long...in order to develop “full resistance “.

2) The holddown is used to keep the shear wall from rotating away from the concrete. If it starts to rotate away, it will unzip the full length of the wall. It seems properly anchored into a post (post must be a minimum of 3” thickness), but I’d make sure all the holes in the metal connector have a screw into the post. What seems odd is the rod  is placed off center of the concrete wall. In order for it to develop full strength, the rod needs to be 1) deformed, 2) set in a 8” wide concrete wall, and 3) encased in concrete about a minimum of 18” (depending on the load it’s resisting. Sometimes they are 48” long...but I’d expect it to have a larger diameter.)

I’d ask the builder why this doesn’t match up to the others and I’d call it to the attention of the Building Inspector.  You did get a Building Permit, right?

Comment: Oh, I’d check the coupling on the holddown to make sure it’s installed properly. There should be two small set screws that need to be screwed all the way in, or the whole holddown is useless.

Comment: I don't see a head it looks like a standard seismic anchor for my area. But the set screws look inaccessible I thought they had to be out.

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure what you mean about the screws, I linked a picture of the full panel. In regards to the building permit, I am purchasing through a home builder (KHovnanian), so they are taking care of all that. http://s1343.photobucket.com/user/gammaupsilonpledgeclass2012/media/IMG_20180211_120826_zpsr93pdan8.jpg.html

Comment: @DerekFong That steel connector (about 2” x 3” x 8”) hanging on the wood post needs to be fastened to the post with screws...not nails...and all the holes in it need a screw placed in it. However, more important is the steel rod coupling. MAKE SURE THE SET SCREWS ARE SET CORRECTLY on both halves of the coupling.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I appreciate you spending time to explain this to me . Yes, they do appear to be fastened with screws. Here is a picture of the steel connector. My original photo was zoomed in on the area that I thought was a problem. If I understand you correctly, the rod being out of position shouldn't be an issue so long as it is fastened properly. My other concern was that the rod would be pushing against the OSB, and that it would result in an uneventful wall. http://s1343.photobucket.com/user/gammaupsilonpledgeclass2012/media/IMG_20180211_123223_zpsohw77jpz.jpg.html

Comment: @DerekFong The rod against the OSB board does not bother me as much as not knowing exactly how long the rod is embedded into the concrete with ADEQUATE amount of concrete cover around the rod. When I see a rod that far out of position, it indicates the balance of the rod could be out of position. However, the coupling is even more important. I would check the set screws to make sure they are in proper position. When I get to work tomorrow, I’m going to check my catalog to verify how to check their position. I’ll be in touch.

Comment: @leesam Okay, the coupling will be something I check on. It is definitely not normal for the builder to use it. Is the coupling used  to attach a separate steel rod? My other anchor on this wall looks normal.I will do another inspection before my inspection with my builder some time next week. California code for the anchor bolt depth is 7 inches. Is there anyway for me to verify it meets the requirements given that it does appear stretched out? I will also check on the set screws. Here is a pic of my other anchor.

Comment: Here is the other anchor I mentioned. http://s1343.photobucket.com/user/gammaupsilonpledgeclass2012/media/Screenshot_20180213-074353_zpsfzj0ffoc.png.html?sort=3&o=0

Comment: @DerekFong Oops, my mistake. The coupler does not have set screws, it has “inspection holes” or “witness holes”. These holes are so you can see how far the coupler is screwed into the rod. You want the bottom rod and top rod screwed in just half way each. Otherwise you won’t develop full transfer of the load.  Goggle “Simpson Strong-tie coupler nuts”. No, I don’t know how to verify the bolts are set to their proper depth once the concrete is poured. Are there any extra bolts laying around that you could compare lengths.

Comment: @leesam I will measure other foundations going up and compare to the bottom rod's length before it hits the coupling. The bottom rod doesn't seem much longer  than the other rod I referenced in my last comment. I assume there is no way for me to know if each side is screwed in properly, short of screwing it myself. Although unconventional, it sounds like there shouldn't be an issue with the structure.